# JDBC: Communication Link Failure

Tags: java, networking, jdbc, vpn

I need an advice. I have a Java Swing program which uses MySQL database. **The MySQL database is in a Linux server and the access is given via a VPN**. Below is my JDBC connectivity code.

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+ip+":3306/databaseName","user","password");
```

As you can see, user of the software can set the `ip` at his side. This is done via the GUI.
So for an example, if the `IP` is 127.0.0.1, then the connection will be set to below.

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/databaseName","user","password");
```

I have hard codded the `user`and `password` as well, but I have asked them to create a user account in MySQL with that user name and the password.

AS far as I know, this is the way Java connects to any database, whether it is local or remote or even via VPN. But my client conplaints about `Communication Link Failure` error. So is the JDBC connection way is different when you are connecting via a VPN? Or else, you have to change the `port` as well? I have hard codded the port to 3306.

As a freelance programmer, I believe client's network admin might have done something wrong, unless the hard codded port is an issue. any advice please?

**UPDATE**

**127.0.0.1** IS JUST FOR AN EXAMPLE...

Comment: Can you can ping the mysql port from the swing app host? If not then it is a network issue. BTW: ip of 127.0.0.1 is for localhost. Are you running mysql and the swing app on the same host?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is your local machine. The port could be different. The VPN may not be connected to the same network as the mysql server. Can you connect to it with a JDBC client like SQuirreL?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: THanks for the reply. You mean the `JDBC` CONNECTION code is correct, but the port might be different?

Comment: @Sniper Of course it could be different. It's configurable.